# New view not listed in view category

Tags: views

I am trying to edit the content of panel to insert a block view I created into a region. When I click on add content and click on the views category, my view is not listed. I flushed the cache and it still doesn't show in the list. I checked the other categories to make sure that it was not showing up. Am I missing a setting somewhere?